# Slow array access in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.9.3

I would like to present you this small (in this reduced form senseless) snippet of ruby code, which runs awfully slow:

```
MAX = 28123
M = 7000

abundant = Array.new(M) {|k| k}
checked = Array.new(MAX) {|k| false}

for a in 0..M-1 do
    for b in a..M-1 do
        checked[abundant[a] + abundant[b]] = true if abundant[a] + abundant[b] < MAX
    end
end
```

It takes about 10 seconds to execute, whereas the equivalent C++ code runs in about 0.2 secs:

```
int main()
{
    int abundant[M];
    bool checked[MAX];               

    for (int n = 0; n < M; n++)
        abundant[n] = n;
    for (int n = 0; n < MAX; n++)
        checked[n] = false;

    for (int a = 0; a < M; a++)
        for (int b = a; b < M; b++)
            if (abundant[a] + abundant[b] < MAX)
                checked[abundant[a] + abundant[b]] = true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the ruby implementation? I'm new to ruby - do I use any statement which is known to be thaaat slow?

Comment: Runs < 3s for me, including Ruby spin up. In any case, (a) it's interpreted, (b) there's object creation, (c) you're running a block to init those objects, etc. Apples, oranges.

Comment: But 0.2s vs. 3s is still not really acceptable for such a simple task. The array creation is not the crucial point (as easily seen when adding a `puts "init done"` message), it's the nested loop which makes the difference. What do you mean by "there's object creation"? Is there such within the loop?

Comment: Yes, but would C allow you to do this: `abundant = Array.new(2*M-1,true) + Array.new(MAX-2*M-1,false)`? Often, in Ruby, you can perform operations speedily--as well as succinctly--by using built-in methods (or methods provided by gems) that have been implemented in C and optimized.

Comment: Could you change the C++ version to use `std::vector` and `.at()` to access the array and then compare with the Ruby version?

Comment: If some ruby is only 10x slower then C then you're having a good day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby is definitely a lot slower than C++, so there is not a lot you could do to make your code faster.

I believe the following code has the same behaviour and is a bit faster (±25%):

```
MAX = 28123
M = 7000

checked = Array.new(MAX) {|k| false}

(0..M - 1).each do |a|
  (a..M - 1).each do |b|
    checked[a + b] = true if a + b < MAX
  end
end
```

Using #each makes no difference, but making fewer array access does. I believe one of the reasons C++ is so much faster is because it makes no boundary check for array accesses while Ruby has to do it.

Could you change the C++ version to use `std::vector` and `.at()` to access the array and then compare with the Ruby version?

Comment: Your suggested improvement is clearly faster, but not usable for the unsimplified problem. But: In the meantime I compared the execution speeds of another different problem and had to observe the same gap. Evidently it's really ruby's interpreter which is slow.

Comment: @JulianS Of course it is--it's an interpreter. You're also using a slower version. It's not really clear what point you're trying to make--it's not exactly a news flash that Ruby is significantly slower than compiled C.